# android cannot import actionmenupresenter in appcompat23.3.0

Tags: android, android-appcompat

Old build.gralde

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

When I update appcompat to latset version [23.3.0]:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
```

`mToolbar.setMenu(mb, new ActionMenuPresenter(getActivity()));`

`ActionMenuPresenter` cannot be resolved.

I found out the source code of `ActionMenuPresenter`

```
class ActionMenuPresenter extends BaseMenuPresenter
        implements ActionProvider.SubUiVisibilityListener {

    private static final String TAG = "ActionMenuPresenter";
    private OverflowMenuButton mOverflowButton;
    private Drawable mPendingOverflowIcon;
}
```

Package is `default` not `public`.

Please some help me!! How to fix the error.

---

`EDIT:`

I found out the solution to fix the question like this:

```
mToolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(
     new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                return onToolBarOptionsItemSelected(item, 
                      mToolbar.getMenu());
            }
});
```

Comment: You can't use the ActionMenuPresenter class. Also it is in the internal package.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I Know!  I mean that how make code to run.

Comment: @Chiclaim, where does it (onToolBarOptionsItemSelected) come from ?

Comment: @sowmia I define for myself